# Curl проблемы с отправкой POST

Tags: php, curl

Добрый день!

Есть код отправки данных на сервер. Проблема в том, что с локального хостинга (Open Server) всё прекрасно уходит, а если скрипт загружен на сервер, то возвращает bool(false). В логах на сервере, куда должны приходить данные, показывает, что запрос туда вообще не приходит. В чем может быть дело?

Спасибо!

```
    $post_data = array (  
    "first_name" => $_POST['name'],  
    "email" => $_POST['email'],  
    "phone" => $_POST['phonecode'] . $_POST['phone'], 
    "ip" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 
    "source" => "Контакты", 
    "language" => "RU", 
    "country" => $_POST['country'], 
    "form" => "форма", 
    "description" => $_POST['pageTitle'] . '\n' . $_POST['message']  , 
);  


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://...' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$out = curl_exec( $curl );

curl_close( $curl );
  var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка здесь:

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Вы передаете массив, но нужно передавать строку:

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
```

Про [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. Сейчас вставил проверку 

if(curl_exec($curl) === false)
{
    echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($curl);
} 
- возвратило "Could not resolve host"

Comment: @Valeriy А с такой ошибкой Вам сюда - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937157/could-not-resolve-host-when-trying-to-install-rvm